# Android Listview deleted checked box Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

Using Listview, I deleted item if check box is checked.

Although it has been implemented through googling, it does not work when you press the checkbox and then press the delete button.

I wrote it like the source below, but nothing reacts. What should I fix?

<MainActivity.kt>

```
lv.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
val del = binding.delBtn
val lv = binding.lvMainMusic
    del.setOnClickListener {

            val count: Int = mainAdapter.count
            if (count > 0) {
                val checked: Int = lv.checkedItemPosition
                if (checked > -1 && checked < count) {
                    playList.removeAt(checked)
                    mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    lv.clearChoices()
                }
            }
        }



}
```

<Music_items.xml>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album_img"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="singer" />


</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/choose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So what I understood from the question is that whenever the user checks an item and then clicks on delete, you want to remove that checked item from the list and update the UI accordingly in listView. Generally, when you want to remove that item you have to remove it from the mainAdapter's list. Something like

```
mainAdapter.remove(checked)
```

And in mainAdapter you have a method defined that removes the item at that position from its list like

```
fun remove(position: Int){
    playList.remove(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, playList.size)
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the question..